# this: SomeObject => object construct

Tags: scala

I was reading up on best practices for implementing Slick, and was examining [this example](https://github.com/knoldus/slick-starting-on-the-right-foot/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/knol/db/repo/BankRepository.scala). In it, there is this construct:

```
trait BankRepository extends BankTable { this: DBComponent =>
   ... //A bunch of code
}
```

I don't understand the `this: DBComponent =>` part. In this case, `DBComponent` is a simple trait defined elsewhere (you can find it in the above link). What I don't understand is:

- What does the `this: DBComponent =>` construct *do*. My IDE doesn't complain, but it also doesn't link to the function being executed by the `=>`. My intuition is that it's saying the rest of the code is a value that is returned, but I'm not clear on what is invoking it, or what the value returned exactly.
- What do I even call this construct? As with many symbol-heavy constructs it's hard to look up/find documentation of, because it's clearly dependent on context. But even describing the context is difficult. What is this construct called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a *self type*. It's basically a contract that says any class extending this trait (mixing it in) **must** include `DBComponent`.  And, as such, the compiler should assume `DBCompenent` elements are in scope for the following code.

Here's a [link](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/modular-programming-using-objects.html#27.4) to a description of it from *Programming in Scala*, Odersky et al, 1st Edition (a little dated but still accurate on most topics).

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a link to documentation around this? Also, should this be considered a one-liner that is magically lifted to the type description, or does what follows impact it? Could I put it in the middle of the trait, for instance?

Comment: I've only ever seen it at the top of the trait/class code.  Some quick experiments with the IntelliJ IDE indicate that the compiler rejects it if it's not at the top.

Comment: My experiments yielded the same result, but I wasn't sure exactly how the compiler got at type information inside the braces. (Well beyond my understanding of compilers.) Thanks for the help!